# Expected type of geom is integer,smallint or bigint but USER-DEFINED was found

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I have tried importing my multilinestring shapefile from both qgis and the shapefile loader into postgis, but it gives me the following error when running the following code:

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('migration.streams', 0.00001, 'id', 'geom', clean:=True);
```

> NOTICE:  PROCESSING: NOTICE:  pgr_createTopology('migration.streams',
> 1e-05, 'id', 'geom', 'source', 'target', rows_where := 'true', clean
> := t) NOTICE:  Performing checks, please wait ..... NOTICE:  ----> PGR
> ERROR in pgr_createTopology: Wrong type of Column id:geom HINT:
> ----> Expected type of geom is integer,smallint or bigint but USER-DEFINED was found NOTICE:  Unexpected error raise_exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pgr_createTopology(edge_table, tolerance, [options])
options: [the_geom, id, source, target, rows_where, clean]
```

You have your id and geom column reversed.  It should be:

`SELECT pgr_createTopology('migration.streams', 0.00001, 'geom', 'id', clean:=True);`

Also, if you use named parameters, you can use whatever order you want for the options:

`SELECT pgr_createTopology('migration.streams', 0.00001, id:='id', geom:='geom', clean:=True);`

or

`SELECT pgr_createTopology('migration.streams', 0.00001, clean:=True, id:='id', geom:='geom');`

etc.